# How to get all Karaf logs?

Tags: logging, web, karaf

I'm using Apache Karaf 2.3.2 
and there is installed my web application.
How to get all karaf logs
to display ones on web page.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by looking at what's in the boot logs at `${karaf.home}/etc/data/karaf.out` and the karaf logfile at `${karaf.home}/etc/data/log/karaf.log`. The location of log files can be configured in the files:

```
${karaf.home}/etc/java.util.logging.properties
${karaf.home}/etc/org.apache.karaf.log.cfg
${karaf.home}/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg
```

Please read the documentation before posting such questions.